# Circles inscribed in regular polygons in hyperbolic geometry

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Does the radius of a circle matter when determining the number sides of a regular polygon in hyperbolic geometry? The sides must be tangent to the circle. Can't I just use an equilateral triangle every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Euclidean geometry, the radius does not matter — one can superscribe a regular $n$-gon around a circle of radius $r$, for every $n\ge 3$ and every $r>0$.

But in hyperbolic geometry, $n$ must grow with $r$. The reason is the *divergence of geodesics* from one another, a hallmark of hyperbolic geometry. When trying to circumscribe an $n$-gon, we pick $n$ equally spaced points on the circle and draw geodesics tangent to the circle at those points. The issue is that when $r$ is large enough, those geodesics never meet each other and no polygon is formed.

This is apparent in the [Beltrami–Klein model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami%E2%80%93Klein_model) of the hyperbolic plane, where geodesics are straight line segments which appear to end at the ideal boundary (in red below). The picture shows a failed attempt to circumscribe a square around the blue circle.

[image: example]

This circle is too bid for $n=4$ to work; one needs more sides.

---

By the way, the special case $n=3$ is an illustration of the definition of a [$\delta$-hyperbolic space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%94-hyperbolic_space) (which is a concept generalizing the hyperbolic plane): a geodesic triangle cannot be "fat", in particular it cannot contain a large disk inside of it.