# For what $n$ does a hyperbolic regular $n$-gon exist around a circle?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Does there exist a relationship in terms of $r$ and $n$ to represent how large $n$ must be if $r$ of the circle is given in the hyperbolic plane? (The edges of the regular $n$-gon are tangent to the circle.)

This is a follow-up question to [Circles inscribed in regular polygons in hyperbolic geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271890/circles-inscribed-in-regular-polygons-in-hyperbolic-geometry/1272244#1272244)

Comment: just a starting idea: is there an formula for the  euclidean similar problem : given 2 concentric circles ( the boundary circle and the inner circle)  what is the lowest n - reg n- gon that fits between them? and then a bit retweaking to this problem

Comment: What is not clear about the question (or the answers?)

Answer (score 1):

In the picture (Klein model) below it is clearly shown that the half of the central angle $\Phi(=\frac{2\pi}{n})$ equals the the [angle of parallelism belonging to $\rho$, the radius of the circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_parallelism). That is, $$\Pi(\rho)\ge \frac{\pi}{n}$$ or equivalently $$n\ge \frac{\pi}{\Pi(\rho)}$$is the condition that the tangent lines meet within the plane or exactly on the absolute.

One of the known formulas for the angle of parallelism is
$$\tan(\Pi(\rho))=\frac{1}{\sinh(\rho)}.$$
Whit this, our condition is 
$$\frac{1}{\sinh(\rho)} \ge \tan \frac{\pi}{n} >\frac{\pi}{n}, $$
since $n\ge 3.$ From here
$$\pi \sinh(\rho)< n.$$
Or

> $$\frac{\circ \rho}{2}  < n,$$

where $\circ \rho$ is the circumference of the hyperbolic circle of radius $\rho$. Note that the last three inequalities give sufficient conditions only. But if $n$ is large enough they are sharp lower bounds for $n$. Think of ($\tan(x)>x$).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Different aproach:

we can just assume that the circle you want to circumscribe is centererd at the centre of the disk of the Beltrami Klein Model. 
and that the segments of the n-gon are just lines  in this model.

Then from Euclidean geometry we now from [Regular n-gon between two concentric circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273842/regular-n-gon-between-two-concentric-circles?lq=1)

we learn $n \geq \pi/\cos^{-1} r/R $

with $ r$ and $R$ being the **euclidean** measures

Taking $R=1$ we get $n \geq \pi/\arccos( r) $

Then in the Beltrami klein model we have for the length

$ h = 1/2 \ln(\frac{ 1+r}{1-r}) $

or $r = \frac{e^{2h}-1}{e^{2h}+1} $

where h = the hyperbolic radius of the circle

so putting it all together you get:

$$n \geq \frac{\pi}{\arccos(  \frac{e^{2h}-1}{e^{2h}+1})} $$