# Regular n-gon between two concentric circles

Tags: geometry

(this question is related to [For what $n$ does a hyperbolic regular $n$-gon exist around a circle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273769/in-hyperbolic-geometry-if-a-circle-radius-r-is-circumscribed-by-a-reg-n-gon) )

Given two concentric circles $ C_r$ with radius $r$ and $C_R$ with radius $R$

what is the lowest regular n -gon (lowest n) that fits between them ? (if i knew that i could answer the related question)

Comment: Assuming that you want the $n$-gon to touch the inner circle and be inside the bigger one: The ratio of the distances from the center of a regular $n$-gon  to a vertex vs. to the midpoint of a side is $1/\cos(\pi/n)$. So it looks like you need $n$ large enough that $R\cos(\pi/n)>r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,
$r$ is the radius of the inner circle
and
$R$ is the radius of the outer circle,
so $r < R$.

For a circumscribed $n$-gon
for a circle of radius
$r$,
the central half-angle is
$\pi/n$,
so the distance to the
outer point $d$
satisfies
$r/d
=\cos(pi/n)
$
or
$d
=r/\cos(pi/n)
$.
Therefore
$R 
\ge r/\cos(pi/n)
$
or
$\cos(\pi/n)
\ge r/R
$
or
$\pi/n
\le \cos^{-1} r/R
$
or
$n
\ge \pi/\cos^{-1} r/R
$.

For an inscribed $n$-gon
in a circle of radius $R$,
if $d$ is the distance
to the center of the sides
of the $n$-gon,
$d/R
=\cos(\pi/n)
$.
Since the inner circle
can not be larger than
this $d$,
$r \le R\cos(\pi/n)$
or
$\cos(\pi/n)
\ge r/R
$
or,
again
$\pi/n 
\le \cos^{-1}(r/R)
$
or
$n
\ge
\pi/\cos^{-1}(r/R)
$.

So
my bound is
$n
\ge
\pi/\cos^{-1}(r/R)
$.

Comment: Can this be readily generalized to spheres of arbitrary dimension?